# Как разместить C# телеграмм бота на Heroku?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, heroku

Имеется простой бот в VS, который ничего не принимает, только иногда проверяет Гугл таблицу и отправляет мне инфо. Как правильно его развернуть на Heroku? И если никак, то какие еще есть доступные студенту варианты?

Comment: Создайте на Azure бесплатную учетную запись. Разместите там бота. Если только Вы им будете пользоваться, то вряд ли выйдете за ограничения бесплатного плана. [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-dotnet-bot-visual-studio)

Comment: юзайте **netcore** и любой free *nix хостинг